# Why is the Bonferroni procedure applicable only when the effects to be investigated are identified in advance of the study?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons

From Kutner's Applied Linear Statistical Models

> In the next three sections, we shall discuss three multiple comparison
>   procedures for analysis of variance models that permit the family
>   confidence coefficient and the family a  risk to be controlled.
>
> Two of these procedures, the Tukey and Scheffe procedures, allow data
>   snooping to be undertaken naturally without affecting the confidence
>   coefficient or significance level.
>
> The other procedure, the Bonferroni procedure, is applicable **only
>   when the effects to be investigated are identified in advance of the
>   study**.

Why is the Bonferroni procedure "applicable only
 when the effects to be investigated are identified in advance of the
 study"?

Is it the same case for the Tukey and Scheffe procedures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because you need to determine the number of tests you're going to correct with the Bonferroni procedure. With the Scheffé & Tukey's HSD procedures this is already determined by the number of possible contrasts & pairwise comparisons respectively.

Comment: Then shouldn't they say "in advance of the analysis"?

Comment: Everyone decides on the analysis before they conduct the study, don't they ;)

Comment: Of course they do.  I've never seen anybody do otherwise.  They also completely understand why that is crucial to having interpretable p-values.